# Render SVG font in Adobe Illustrator or Corel Draw

Tags: fonts, svg, adobe-illustrator, coreldraw

I'm developing a project that produces SVG files with custom embed fonts. SVG font definition I compose as SVG font tag with help of http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator or Batik SVG Toolkit. The resulted SVG file I try to open in following applications:

- Adobe Illustrator CS4 - text has default font and message noticed about font not found in system
- CorelDRAW X5 - text has default font and any messages don't noticed
- Batik SVG Browser (Squiggle) - renders text correctly

The problem is all modern typographies use CorelDRAW and Abode Illustrator for print vector graphic and them render not correctly SVG.

**Solution**

As for me, I see follow solutions:

- Save the text with custom font as SVG path. This will work but, I can't find any solution that can convert text + TTF to SVG path data;
- Use other vector format, f.e. AI, EPS or CDR. This solution is difficult for me, because I use SVG paths as part of input data;
- Recommend our users to use Batik SVG Browser (Squiggle) or any other application which are based on Batik SVG Toolkit library. Batik SVG Toolkit requires Java runtime :(

If anyone know some knowledge to open SVG embed fonts in Adobe Illustrator, CorelDRAW or tools which can convert text + TTF to SVG path data please share them. I would be grateful for any help.

Thank you.
-Viktor Burdeinyi

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your fonts in SVG file you need to convert that in outlines.

In Illustrator right click to font and click to ***Create Outlines***

Answer (score 0):

The free open source program inkscape has font designing capabilities built into it, so I can only assume that it would be able to open svg font files. You can download inkscape here- http://inkscape.org/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by selecting **Create Outlines**
Just select any text you want, right-click, and then select **Create Outlines** as shown in the below screenshot.
[image]